# Forge Viewer Custom Combox/ComboButton

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

Hi I'm trying to add a custom combox, this is my code

```
  addCustomCombox(parentCtrl: any) {

    //create combox
    const comboButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ComboButton('buildings');
    comboButton.setToolTip('buildings');

    //create button
    var button1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('show-env-bg-button');
    button1.onClick = function (e) {
      alert('test');
    };
    button1.addClass('show-env-bg-button');
    button1.setToolTip('Show Environment');

    //attach button to combox
    comboButton.addControl(button1);

    parentCtrl.addControl(comboButton)
  }
```

Howeve I'm getting an error on `comboButton.addControl()` it says expected 0 arguments. I checked in node modules and this is the function for ComboButton

```
  class ComboButton extends Button {
    constructor(id: string, options?: object);

    addControl(): void;
    restoreDefault(): void;
    saveAsDefault(): void;
  }
```

`addControl` doesn't accept any parameters. So how do I create a custom combox? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

**stackoverflow reference: [Forge Viewer Extension for Toolbar: How to add a custom combox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957086/forge-viewer-extension-for-toolbar-how-to-add-a-custom-combox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you using typescript definition?

just modify it like this:

```
      class ComboButton extends Button {
        constructor(id: string, options?: object);

        addControl(button: any): void;
        restoreDefault(): void;
        saveAsDefault(): void;
      }
```

Comment: Paxton's right. The TypeScript definition for Forge Viewer is written by hand, and unfortunately this is a typo. The `ComboButton#addControl` method does accept a `Button` object as its argument.

Comment: Also, whenever you run into an issue like this, please feel free to report an issue to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues (specify `@types/forge-viewer` in the title).

Comment: Thank you guys, issue is fixed now. I opted not to use the typescript definitions